# Pandas DataFrame Add a Column Based on a String

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have the following column in pandas data frame:
[image]

In the "Stats" Column, each statistic is separated by spaces. I would like to create new columns for each statistic. The problem is that not each row has every type of stat. E.g. row 2 doesn't have "trey" in it. How do I accomplish this feat?

I tried this, but it just added new columns after each ' ':

```
nba_2017_revised4 = nba_2017_revised3.join(nba_2017_revised3['Stats'].str.split(' ', 7, expand=True).rename(columns={0:'Points', 1:'Rebounds', 2:'Assists', 3:'Steals', 4:'Turnovers', 5:'3_Pointers', 6:'FG_Attempts', 7:'FT_Attempts'}))
```

[image]

```
Date    First Last  Stats   Minutes DKP Team    Opp DRPM
0   20170412.0  Ron Baker   8pt 1rb 4as 2to 1trey 3-6fg 1-2ft   29.350000   14.75   nyk phi -0.56
1   20170409.0  Ron Baker   11pt 8rb 8as 1st 2to 1trey 5-12fg   38.100000   34.50   nyk tor -0.56
2   20170407.0  Ron Baker   2pt 2rb 7as 1to 1-7fg   30.500000   14.50   nyk mem -0.56
3   20170406.0  Ron Baker   12pt 2rb 2as 2to 5-9fg 2-2ft    27.166667   16.50   nyk was -0.56
4   20170404.0  Ron Baker   9pt 4rb 6as 2st 4to 1trey 4-7fg 0-1ft   37.300000   25.50   nyk chi -0.56
```

Thanks.

Comment: No images please add the data in the form of text. How can we copy the data to try our solution.

Comment: What is the expected output

Comment: nba_2017_revised4 = nba_2017_revised3.join(nba_2017_revised3['Stats'].str.split(' ', 7, expand=True).rename(columns={0:'Points', 1:'Rebounds', 2:'Assists', 3:'Steals', 4:'Turnovers', 5:'3_Pointers', 6:'FG_Attempts', 7:'FT_Attempts'}))

Comment: Please add the expected output in the question. So we better understand your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use regex to parse each split by taking the consecutive letters at the end as the column values and the string prior as the value.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

pat = lambda x: re.match('^(.+?)([a-z]+)$', x).groups()
prs = lambda s: pd.Series(*zip(*[pat(x) for x in s.split()]))

df.drop('Stats', 1).join(df.Stats.apply(prs))

       Date First   Last    Minutes    DKP Team  Opp  DRPM as    fg   ft  pt rb   st to trey
0  20170412   Ron  Baker  29.350000  14.75  nyk  phi -0.56  4   3-6  1-2   8  1  NaN  2    1
1  20170409   Ron  Baker  38.100000  34.50  nyk  tor -0.56  8  5-12  NaN  11  8    1  2    1
2  20170407   Ron  Baker  30.500000  14.50  nyk  mem -0.56  7   1-7  NaN   2  2  NaN  1  NaN
3  20170406   Ron  Baker  27.166667  16.50  nyk  was -0.56  2   5-9  2-2  12  2  NaN  2  NaN
4  20170404   Ron  Baker  37.300000  25.50  nyk  chi -0.56  6   4-7  0-1   9  4    2  4    1
```

Comment: I was excited to see your results, piRSquared, but I got the following error when trying the code:  AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @GilO'Brien That's because some of your values in the `Stats` column are `np.nan` which are defined as `float`.  You should fill na values with `''`.  Try this `df.drop('Stats', 1).join(df.Stats.fillna('').apply(prs))`

Comment: I'm glad it worked... you can do a digital beer, aka upvote and accepted answer (-:

Comment: You got it.  The least I could do.